# Match pattern in a file ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to search a string in a file (mostly a .txt file) and return `true` if there is a match. I've tried multiple solutions such as follows:

```
# 1.
File.foreach('C:\InstallList.txt').grep /Java/

# 2.
File.open("C:/InstallList.txt") do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    if line =~ '/Java/'
      puts "Found Java: #{line}"
    else
      puts "Not found"
    end
  end
end
```

But none of these seem to work. Please help as I this seems a very trivial thing, but still not happening.

```
# 3. 
File.each_line('c:/InstallList.txt') do |li|
  puts li if (li[/Java/])
end
```

Here is a snippet of the InstallList.txt file.

> swMSM                                                                    12.0.0.1
>   Microsoft Office Live Meeting 2007                                       8.0.6362.190
>   Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5                                             4.5.50709
>   Google Update Helper                                                     1.3.24.15
>   Vagrant                                                                  1.6.1
>   Windows Azure Storage Tools - v2.2.2                                     2.2.2.0
>   Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable                                8.0.61001
>   AWS Command Line Interface                                               1.3.17
>   Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.4148           9.0.30729.4148
>   Microsoft Silverlight                                                    5.1.30214.0
>   Oracle VM VirtualBox 4.3.10                                              4.3.10
>   Java Auto Updater                                                        2.1.9.5
>   RapidBoot Shield                                                         1.23

Comment: Your second probably works, but you are not using the regular expression `/Java/`, but the *string* `'/Java/'`. Try to change that to the regex and see if that works. It should actually give an error because `=~` does not work on a right hand side String. Does `InstallList.txt` actually exist :)?

Comment: @Daniël, I don't understand what you mean in your penultimate sentence: `"Java or tea?" =~ /Java/ #=> 0`, `/Java/ =~ "Java or tea?" #=> 0`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You are right, I was not being fully accurate there. I should have said it does not work *when both sides are a String*, i.e., `"Java" =~ '/Java/'` will fail. In his situation the left side was already a String. But you were right to correct me thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could read the entire file into a string:

```
if File.read('file.txt') =~ /Java/
  # ...
end
```

Or process it line by line:

```
if File.foreach('file.txt').any? { |line| line =~ /Java/ }
  # ...
end
```

In case you're dealing with a file encoding other than ASCII / UTF-8, you have to specify it when opening the file. To open a UTF-16 file with BOM you'd use:

```
File.read('file.txt', mode: 'r:BOM|UTF-16:UTF-8')
```

Comment: Hi, I tried both your solutions, and inside the loop I just print a "Success" string. But the code doesn't seem to work, as it prints nothing. I'm using 1.9.3 btw

Comment: @gfc both work for me, maybe your file doesn't contain the pattern?

Comment: I updated the question with a snippet of the file. The sad thing is, it contains the pattern :(

Comment: BTW, your snipped works for me, i.e. `File.read('file.txt') =~ /Java/` returns 425